# Odoo Facebook messenger intrgartion using webhooks needs conflicting controller type

Tags: facebook, odoo, facebook-messenger, odoo-14, facebook-webhooks

I am trying to integrate the Facebook messenger with Odoo using the steps mentioned in this document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook.

One of the first steps is setting up and validating the webhook URL which sends an HTTP get request to the URL mentioned to validate which I was able to complete & authenticate

[image]

the controller that is  written for the above request is as below

```
@http.route('/get_message_from_facebook', type='http',method=['GET'], auth='none')
def get_message_from_facebook(self, **kwarg):
```

however the next steps on this is that Facebook automatically sends data to the same URL for events we bave setup but these requests are of json type which leads to the error below.

> facebook_integration odoo.http: <function CustomFacebookController.get_message_from_facebook at 0x7fbbd41f7620>, /get_message_from_facebook: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'

SO basically i want to know how can one controller handle both json & http type of requests or am i doing something wrong.

ps if i change the type of controller manually after validation the data seems to pullin.

Comment: The actual webhook requests that send the data will be POST requests to begin with (so I don't see how your current setup would even catch that at the moment?) - so add a second route for that method?

Comment: i tried writing a second controller with tye json and method post but it still hits the first controller only since the url is same

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong, I suppose, because a tiny bit of research suggests, that it should work exactly that way - https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-handle-a-single-controller-which-can-accept-both-controller-type-ie-http-and-json-odoo-12-157450 (and funny enough, that question was also asked in a webhook handling context.)

Comment: This was one of the first approaches i used but unfortunately it does not seem to be working as expected which could be perhaps the reason the answer isnt accepted.